# How do I write a nested list of lists with my custom list implementation?

Tags: list, haskell, nested

I am wondering whether my definition of a list is less capable than the regular implementation. I am having problems creating a list of lists with the below definition:

```
data List a =
  Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

I do not see how to create a list like `[[2],[3]]` with my definition of list.

The simplest instance of a nested list is just `[[]]` which I think I can recreate with `Cons Nil Nil`. The second simplest instance of a nested list is `[[1]]`. This is `Cons (Cons 1 Nil) Nil` afaics.

However, like I said do not see how to create the list `[[2],[3]]` with my definition above. How do I do it? (It should be possible, since an exercise asks me to create a monad instance for the list definition above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first consider, how would you express `[x,y]`?

```
Cons x (Cons y Nil)
```

Now put in `x = [2]`:

```
Cons (Cons 2 Nil) (Cons y Nil)
```

and `y = [3]`:

```
Cons (Cons 2 Nil) (Cons (Cons 3 Nil) Nil)
```

Comment: I am amazed that I was able to understand how to make the monad instance but not see this. Must have forgotten a Nil somewhere and had the REPL choke. Oh, well.